# How to remove this blue edge selection?

Tags: edges

I have used bevel, boolean and many modifiers I have forgotten. The problem is the edge and is blue in color. What edge selection is that? I have cleared seams and checked mean crease is 0. So may I know what is this edge select mark in blue and how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: I got the answer it was sharpen edges

Answer (score 4):

To fix this follow these steps:

1. Go into *Edit Mode* and select all edges by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
3. Click *Clear Sharp*

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. But "clear sharp" does not work. Some edges still remain blue and sharp. I also tried unchecking Autosmooth normals ... going to Mesh menu and doing stuff like "smooth vectors" or other options did not work either. Is there a way?

Comment: @ArashHooshangnezhad  I guess the overlay _could_  be confused with Bevel Weight.. is that clear, too ?

Answer (score 2):

And if you don't want to clear sharpness, but still don't see the blue overlay, do the following:
*Edit mode > Properties Panel > Mesh Display > Uncheck Sharp*.