# When import OBJ the edge becomes 'strong'

Tags: obj

[image]

when I import OBJ file. The edge becomes 'strong'.
some edges are good, but most of them are like this in picture.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for, but what you're seeing is edges that are marked "sharp", If you want them gone, select the whole mesh (in edit mode - edge select), right click, and pick "clear sharp".

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69533 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84961

Answer (score 2):

These light blue edges are marked sharp.

[image: Sharp edges]

It means they will be sharp when you Shade Smooth the object and Auto Smooth the Normals

[image: Smooth and Autosmooth]

You can remove them by selecting them, pressing Right mouse button and selecting Clear Sharp

[image]

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome.